# Can't Access Localhost After Running nodemon

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nodemon

I am starting a new project and when I run nodemon server it seems that it isn't listening to the port I specify and it exits instantly. Obviously when I try to access localhost to check, I just get a can't connect message from my browser.

index.js

```
import app from "./server.js"
import mongodb from "mongodb"
import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config()
const MongoClient= mongodb.MongoClient

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.RESTREVIEWS_DB_URI,
    {
        poolSize: 50,
        wtimeout: 2500,
        useNewUrlParse: true }
    )
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err.stack)
        process.exit(1)
    })
    .then(async client => {
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
        })
    })
```

restaurants.route.js

```
import express from "express"

const router = express.Router()

router.route("/").get((req, res) => res.send("Hello, world"))

export default router
```

server.js

```
import express from "express"
import cors from "cors"
import restaurants from "./api/restaurants.route.js"

const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.use("/api/v1/restaurants", restaurants)
app.use("*", (req, res) => res.status(404).json({ error: "not found"}))

export default app
```

I'm following a video so not really sure if it's because my versions aren't exactly the same and some things have changed or what the problem could be.

Comment: Could you add the exact `nodemon` command you're running so it's possible to see what port on localhost you're expecting to work? Also, when you say it exists instantly, could provide the output of running the command?

Comment: @lasse I was just running `nodemon server` or `nodemon server.js` in my terminal with no other parameters. But I think I might have just fixed it if you check my answer below. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my index.js file to the following.

```
import app from "./server.js"
import mongodb from "mongodb"
import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config()
const MongoClient= mongodb.MongoClient

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

MongoClient.connect(
    process.env.RESTREVIEWS_DB_URI,
    {
        wtimeoutMS: 2500 }
    )
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err.stack)
        process.exit(1)
    })
    .then(async client => {
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
        })
    })
```

I removed `poolsize` and `useNewUrlsParse` as they are not supported and then changed `wtimeout` -> `wtimeoutMS` because `wtimeout` is deprecated. After these changes, everything ran fine with `nodemon server`. Not sure if this will come back to bite me in the future, but as it stands now, it is fixed.